# Long reload UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a problem, 
I have empty datasource when i load table,after that when i get data from server
i do this `[tableview reloadData]`
but i have big delay bettwen `numberOfRowsInSection` and `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, so my table look freeze in this time.
Does anybody can help me here!

```
2014-05-20 14:07:02.803[8097:4f03] didReceivePlaces
2014-05-20 14:07:02.809[8097:4f03] numberOfRowsInSection
2014-05-20 14:07:13.310[8097:4f03] cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-05-20 14:07:13.352[8097:4f03] cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-05-20 14:07:13.368[8097:4f03] cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-05-20 14:07:13.383[8097:4f03] cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-05-20 14:07:13.397[8097:4f03] cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

**EDIT**
I find the answer i need to reload table in main thread like this, its work great!
[table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: The log messaging you have added is not enough to narrow where you problem is. Please tell us where you're calling `[tableView reloadData]`. Looks like you have another task running on the main thread that is blocking your UI.

Comment: Yes you are right! I work with server in the same time,so you mantion help me find right way to use
[table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: All UI updates are performed on the main thread. If you try to update any UI on the background you will receive an exception. The only work around would be to run your webservice request to the background, and when you receive the response just update your `tableView` on the main thread. I will give you an example in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending `URLRequest` to your web service your UI is blocked until the response has being received. The solution is to run your request on a separate thread so it doesn't block your UI.

**Example:**

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://www/yourwebsite.com/webservice/";
NSString *postString = @"username=Username&pass=123545";
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL urlQithString:urlStr];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// create NSOperationQueue for your webservice call
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

// rnu your webservice call on the separate operation queue with completion block
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError){

// do whatever you have to do when webservice returns data


//update your tableview on the main thread at the end
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your UITableView on the main thread. UI updates should ALWAYS be done on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [tableview reloadData];
        })
```